# Not able to see Application Extension (App Builder) option in ArcGIS online account?

Tags: widget, publish, arcgis, portal

I want to publish custom widget in my ARCGIS portal account but I am not able to publish that because that Application Extension (App Builder) option is not visible in my Account [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option is not available in ArcGIS Online (the SAAS product that Esri runs in the cloud). That option is only available in ArcGIS Enterprise (Portal), which is the version that you install on your own servers.